# Meaning of the "k" on this matlab plot

Tags: python, matlab, octave

My teacher asked me to pass some code from Octave to Python and I don´t have a lot of knowledge on this, they are plot functions and he asked me to use plotly . One of the files have this code, overall i think the translation is almost the same except some small thing but I´m trying to understand the meaning of the "k+" and "ko" to know what to search to convert to Python, or if you´re good enough to tell me how to do it I would appreciate it a lot.

This is the code to be converted:

```
    pos = find(y==1); neg = find(y == 0);

    plot(X(pos, 1), X(pos, 2), 'k+','LineWidth', 2, ...'MarkerSize', 7);
    plot(X(neg, 1), X(neg, 2), 'ko', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'y', ...'MarkerSize', 7);
```

This is how I´ve been trying to convert it to Python:

```
def plotdata(x, y):

    pos = find(y == 1)
    neg = find(y == 0)
    plotData(x(pos, 1), x(pos, 2), linewidth=2, markersize=7)
    plotData(x(neg, 1), x(neg, 2), markerfacecolor,markersize=7)
```

Comment: k means black.. + and o are markers

Comment: Here's the MATLAB documentation to `plot`: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html . Now you can read what this means.

Comment: [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/matplotlib_markers.asp) are color, size, line etc. references

Answer (score 3):

The `'k+'` and `'ko'` are strings that specify the line style for the data being plotted.

`'k'` means draw a black line, `'+'` will draw '+' markers at each of the points, and `'o'` will draw circles as markers for each point.

You can learn more about the Matlab plot function [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html).